# Is it possible to have more than one authentication cookie for one web site?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, forms-authentication

Is it possible to have more than one authentication cookie for one web site?

As it turned out it is not possible.

I have the following situation:

2 Web sites (same domain):

- A
- B

2 Authenticationn cookies:

- Website A has authentication cookie A
- Website B has authentication cookie B

Both cookies have sliding expiration enabled. Cookie A is shared between both sites.

When you login on web site A and B you have the two cookies for web site B.
Will the shared cookie A be refreshed regarding sliding expiration when I access web site B?

**EDIT**: The answer is no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just using the built-in forms-authentication, then no.

However, if you create your own (which I would recommend against), then you would be able to.

Answer (score 1):

short answer no, however you can either stuff extra data into the cookie, or define another one with different name, but you have to manage in both cases

to be able to answer better, more details are needed about the problem you are trying to solve

Comment: Is an authentication cookie (owner web site A), that is shared between web site A and B, be refreshed when web site B is accessed?

Comment: What do you mean by "refreshed"? You mean update the sliding timeout?

Comment: Yes, refreshed regarding sliding expiration.